# How can I get events to my (sub) UIView?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

I'm new to Swift and have a hard time understand the event flow. The code below can be run directly in an xcode playground. I have a white UIView in the background. This view has a brown button and a red view as sub-views. Click on them and the events are logged in the controller, just as expected.

But the controller of this white view also adds another view, that has it's own controller class (SubviewController). SubviewController is green and has a blue subview with a black button. Question is... why don't I get any logs from the green, blue and black views/buttons?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class TestViewController : UIViewController {

    let playButton: UIButton = {
        let playButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 155, y: 135, width: 160, height: 40))
        playButton.setTitle("BROWN BUTTON", for: .normal)
        playButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        return playButton
    }()


    override func loadView() {
        let viewWhite = UIView()
        viewWhite.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let viewRed = UIView()
        viewRed.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        viewRed.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 40, height: 10)
        viewRed.clipsToBounds = true
        let recognizer2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.handleTapRed(_:)))
        viewRed.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer2)


        let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.handleTap(_:)))

        viewWhite.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

        playButton.addTarget(self,  action:  #selector (self.action) , for: .touchUpInside)

        let catList = SubviewController()

        viewWhite.addSubview(catList.view)
        viewWhite.addSubview(playButton)
        viewWhite.addSubview(viewRed)
        self.view = viewWhite
    }

    func action() {
        print("Brown button tapped")
    }

    func handleTap(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("WHITE VIEW (background view) TAPPED")
    }

    func handleTapRed(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("RED VIEW TAPPED")
    }

}

class SubviewController: UIViewController {

    let buttonBlack: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 10, width: 170, height: 20))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        button.setTitle("BLACK BUTTON", for: .normal)
        return button
    }()

    let viewBlue: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        v.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 40, width: 240, height: 60)
        v.clipsToBounds = true
        return v
    }()

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        buttonBlack.addTarget(self,  action:  #selector (self.blackKlick) , for: .touchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(viewBlue)

        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: 240, height: 60)
        self.view.clipsToBounds = true

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.handleTapGreen(_:))))

        viewBlue.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.handleTapBlue(_:))))
        viewBlue.addSubview(buttonBlack)
    }

    func blackKlick() {
        print("Black button tapped")
    }

    func handleTapBlue(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("BLUE VIEW TAPPED")
    }

    func handleTapGreen(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("GREEN VIEW TAPPED")
    }
}

 PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = TestViewController()
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in your current code:

```
    let catList = SubviewController()
```

creates a *local* instance of `SubvieController`. As soon as you exit the `loadView()` func, that instance is gone.

So, you need a class-level variable to keep that instance around. Add this line:

```
class TestViewController : UIViewController {

    var catList: SubviewController!
```

and then remove the `let` from the instantiation line in `loadView()`:

```
    catList = SubviewController()
```

Comment: OMG, how stupid... 2 hours without seeing that... thanks a lot!